# Circuit with resistor, diodes

Tags: electrical

I just started to learn electronic circuit. But it's a bit hard to understand this question and there is no explanation on the book.

[image]

The answer is 4mA / +1V.

Comment: You didn't say that the diodes were ideal types with no forward volt drop.

Comment: Tell us how much you do understand about the circuit. What do you know about the behavior of the diodes?

Comment: Ummm.... I'll be honest. Not at all. So, I know what is reverse and forward... and yes all diodes are ideal.

Comment: Try splitting the problem into small problems. Imagine there's only **one** diode, for example the bottom one connected to +1 V, what would \$I\$ and \$V\$ be in that case? Then add **one** diode more, what changes?

Answer (score 0):

Because the bottom (ideal) diode conducts when Vo reaches +1V, it will never achieve the 2-3V needed for the other diodes to conduct.  They can be ignored as open circuit.

The 1V Vo leaves 4V across the resistor.  Apply Ohm's law.